# Can I move objects in a JFrame(JPanel) along lines other than y=0, x=0, y=x and y=-x?

Tags: java, swing, math, move, point

I want to make a program that draws a given number of points moving out from the center of the JPanel in a circle/square to infinity. For example 10 points, the first line is at 0 degrees to the y=0 line, the second is 36 degrees, 72, 108...

My problem is that the coordinates of the points are integers and when I use Math.tan it rounds dX and dY to 0 or 1.

dX = x2 - x1, dY = y2 - y1

For example I want to move one point along a line which is at a 30 degree angle to y=0 line. Tangens of that degree is sqrt(3)/3. dX is always 1 or -1 so dY will be around +/-0,71 so it'll be rounded to 1/-1 and I'll get just another y=x line, 45 degrees.

If I downgrade my program to move the point to a certain moment, I will be able to search for each points end-point and then I'll be able to write a function for their movement which will create a line. Can I move the points along these lines?

Comment: Work with doubles or floats. Also use polar coordinates.

Comment: `Graphics2D` and the `Shape` API can deal with `double` and `float` values. Have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) for more details

Comment: Have a look at things like `Line2D` and `Point2D`, these maintain values in `double` and `float` precision.  You can then use `Graphics2D`'s `draw(Shape)` and `fill(Shape)` methods to render them

Comment: Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signify that this is solved. You also get 2 reputation points for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This moves a point with `double` precision:

```
public class PointMove extends JPanel {

    double r = 200;
    double theta = Math.PI / 4;

    public OpenTets() {

        new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                r = r + 0.05;
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        double x = r * Math.cos(theta);
        double y = r * Math.sin(theta);
        Graphics2D g2d = ((Graphics2D) g);
        g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 5, 5));
    }
}
```

Add this component to a `JFrame` of sufficient size, for example.

The idea is to use `Graphics2D.draw(Shape)` and use a `Double` precision shape, one of [these](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html), to represent a point.

Comment: You're violating the painting chain contract, which will result in numerous and nasty paint artifacts. You should also be creating your UI from within the context of the EDT. Painting should always paint the current state, if you want to maintain what was previously painted, then you should use a buffer or some kind of model which can be used to recreate it. Over all, it's a bad example

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm just demonstrating `double` precision. I could just have posted the `paintComponent` method. True, I don't initialize the GUI from the EDT, but as my profile says, all of that is just a wrapper. The OP already has the shell and their problem is only with precision.

Comment: The problem is, this example demonstrates bad habits/operations/practices which will cause no end of issues for the unwary. "It's just a demo" isn't a good enough excuse for doing the wrong thing. There are also documented cases where not using `EventQueue.invokeLater` to start you UI can result in thread deadlocks on some platforms. If you're going to teach some to one to shoot a gun, do more then show them where the trigger is, otherwise, we could be losing a lot of feet. Oh, and the OP is unlikely to read you profile ;)

Comment: Oh, and I don't disagree with "simple" is best, but that doesn't mean we get lazy and not use best practices, the site is, after all, for professionals by professionals, we should be presenting best practices as a matter of cause, don't want to teach inexperienced developers bad habits

Comment: @MadProgrammer I completely understand, but if every example would follow all best practices etc. it would be bloated and obscure the point. Here I will need to set the visibility modifiers properly, override `getPreferredSize` for the `JPanel` instead of `setSize` for the `JFrame`, manage the threads, remove the `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` which is probably a bad habit and maybe improve some memory management. All for showing `g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(...))`. Let me think about it for a sec.

Comment: So? Remove `main`.  I'm sure the OP is capable of creating a frame, if over bloating the example is of concern (although, if you want to stop the OP from telling you your example doesn't work, `getPreferredSize` might be helpful ;))

Comment: See, that's an example I can get behind ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer As a Swing person yeah, but then comes a software designer and complains about not making `r` and `theta` private and then comes a... Anyway, thanks for the input :)

Comment: Yeah, there's enough bad code on the net, we don't need to be adding to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something called line drawing algorithms, there are multiple ones that will give you varying degrees of smoothness of the line that you can read about at the wiki page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm).

In your case you don't want to draw the line entirely, which means that you need to clear your buffer every time you've identified the new points to draw before plotting them.

Bresenham should give you decent looking lines while not being so complex, you can view it fully [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: I don't think this is relevant. Swing painting already uses drawing algorithms.

Comment: I disagree, see my answer.

Comment: Doesn't make what I say irrelevant in the least bit just another solution.